# Firefox Pseudo element positioning on first word in a line

Tags: html, css, firefox, pseudo-element

Firefox positions pseudo elements on in-line elements such as `<span>` and `<a>` so the they expand to contain the :before or :after element.  This is different to IE and Chrome where the pseudo element is positioned outside of the parent element.  But Firefox behaves very strange if the parent element is at the start of a line.  If you run [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CoolBlue/yarv7rdf/13/) in Firefox you will see what I mean.

Here is the code...
HTML

```
<div><p>Fixie Williamsburg 8-bit, try-hard master cleanse small batch literally
post-ironic. Pug Williamsburg small batch Schlitz, iPhone banh mi irony hella
skateboard <span>Pinterest forage slow-carb</span> try-hard before they sold out
cred. Craft beer keytar farm-to-table, chia twee before they sold out Marfa
hella trust <a>fund</a> biodiesel. Normcore PBR <span>dreamcatcher</span> plaid,
<span>XOXO</span> cornhole crucifix master cleanse fap PBR. Pickled next level
<span>mlkshk</span>, cornhole Godard typewriter master cleanse flannel ethical.
Etsy fixie messenger bag jean shorts, roof party hoodie aesthetic plaid yr
meggings. Mumblecore <span>asymmetrical</span> semiotics DIY tattooed</p></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 400px; 
    overflow: visible;
    outline: solid 1px black;
}
span, a {
/*  display: inline-block;  
*/    color: firebrick;
    position: relative;
    outline: solid 1px red;
    padding: 0;
}

span:hover::before,
a:hover::before{
    display: inline-block;  
    background:  firebrick /* rgba(0,0,0,.8)*/;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: 'tooltip text';
    left: calc(80% - 6px);
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
}

span:hover::after,
a:hover::after{
    display: inline-block;  
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-color:  firebrick transparent/* rgba(0,0,0,.8)*/;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom: 20px;
    content: "";
    left: 80%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my CSS?  The behaviour in IE and Chrome is not ideal for an element flowing onto a new line, but I can live with that...

Is there a way to fix the beginning of a line behaviour in FF?  I'm using FF 36.0.4

Answer (score 0):

You were close! Set the span to `display: inline-block;` and use border instead of an outline.

https://jsfiddle.net/cbsteph/yarv7rdf/15/

```
span, a {
    display: inline-block;  
    color: firebrick;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well and it behaves better. The only reason I didn't settle on that solution was because it breaks the flow for the highlighted elements. Border vs outline doesn't seem to make much difference for me, I only had outlines to make it easy to see what was going on.